# Will my posts (questions and answers) be seen even if I'm new to the site?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Will my posts (questions and answers) be seen even if I'm new to the site or do I need a minimum amount of reputation for it?

Is there a difference between a user with high reputation and a new user in regards to participating in asking questions and writing answers?

Comment: You need a hug.

Comment: change your username ;-)

Comment: Thannk's for the hug and the suggestion. I think my question has been answered in the fact that some über rank dude has completely rewritten my question. Huffffff. :) having said that, I seem to have earned more of reputation in complaining about not having a reputation. Am I learning fast or what?

Answer (score 10):

Repuation points have no bearing on answer quality; people do not (or should not) ignore answer just because they're written by a new user.

In fact, many people will *specifically* upvote (decent) answers by new users to try to welcome them to the site.

---

There is no difference in asking and answering between new users and high-reputation users, except that new users have limitations in post rate and link count as an anti-spam measure.

You do need 1500 reputation to [create new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags), but that shouldn't be an issue, because all the tags you might need when asking questions should already exist.

Comment: +1. Agree. If I spot a new user with a good answer, I'm more likely to upvote to encourage 'good' behaviour. I'll comment on Q & A's that need improving.

Comment: It's the same question in essence. I figured someone would rollback my edit if they didn't like it :)

Answer (score 5):

I took a look at a few of your answers and saw a theme.  You will present a good solution or code that works, but there is not any explanation as to what it is or why it works.  Rather than just generating code, it is preferred that Stack Overflow answers generate knowledge.

I suggest adding more detail and explanation to your answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand your point. But if you're saying that people do not read answer of new users, you are mistaken.

As a person who already asked question, I take attention to each answer that user provides in my threads. Because new user are necessary non-experts or non-technicians.

By the way answering question may provide you vote from people who would have say the same thing as you. Since answer already exists (if it's good quality) they will gratify you with an upvote and leave.

Answer (score 0):

People will answer your questions as long as they are good questions, especially if you vote good answers up and choose to accept an answer.

When people don't answer questions it's usually due to bad questions, not reputation.